# clustering droplet data along trajectories

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, clustering, pandas

I have regular t,x,y,z-datapoints of droplets, that move continuously from top to bottom on different but similar paths. The droplets also have a volume that is approximately measured, they can appear and disappear, merge or split. I want to assign each datapoint to a actual droplet over time.

I implemented an algorithm that iteratively tracks all droplets with an adapted linear sum assignment algorithm, that take into account splitting and merging. However, the algorithm is quite slow as it has to take all possible splitting and merging into account, which increases the cost matrix from frame to frame quite a bit.

To improve performance, I would like to find the trajectories where droplets keep their volume (no split or merge happens) over a period of time by clustering the total data frame. This would save me some expensive calculations

I tried clustering algorithms, but couldn't figure out how to cluster data along a trajectory. Any help would be appreciated!

following sketch shows the problem, two droplets emerge, one splits into two further droplets. I would like to label the datapoints as indicated by differently colored trajecories without expensive iterative optimization.
[image: exemplary sketch of how simplified data would look like]